# How to find or create shortcut icon for installed Atom in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, atom-feed

I'm new to Atom. I have installed it successfully and added a project in it. I want to create a shortcut icon on the desktop but cannot find atom.exe.

I have searched this problem and found that atom.exe is in the `C:\Users\<ypur folder>\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.16.0` folder, but I didn't find the AppData folder in my user account.

Answer (score 0):

I found my atom executable in the local AppData folder under my user profile.

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\atom
```